# Extracting a portion of a string in C from Pointer arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

I am working on a requirement, where I need to extract the hostname from pointer arrays.
I am stuck at a particular juncture looking for guidance here

```
char *A[2]={"opc.tcp://localhost:4840","opc.tcp://localhostagain:4841"}
char *B[]={};

int main(){
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            int length = strlen(A[i]);
            B[i] = (char *)UA_malloc(length+1);
            memcpy(B[i],A[i],strlen(A[i]));
            B[i][length] = 0;
            printf("memcpy of B[i]: %s\n", B[i]);  //just having a backup

            printf("memcpy of C[i]: %s\n", C[i]);
            //new addition to extract port and remove the initial opc.tcp:// binding
            B[i] = A[i] + 10;
            printf("After B[i] = A[i] + 10 : %s\n", B[i]); //prints localhost:4840
            char *p = strrchr(B[i], ':');
            int port = strtoul(p+1, NULL, 10);
            printf("Extracted port : %d\n",port); 
            const char deli[] = ":"
           //Here i am looking to extract the hostname information. 
           //below approach fails
           token = strtok(B[i], deli); 
            printf("%s\n", token); //expect localhost. But fails
         }




}
```

I need the output token: localhost

Any guidance would be welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: This declaration char *B[]={}; in C is invalid.

Comment: To create a copy of a string you don't have to do strlen/malloc/memcpy/add '\0', you can just use strdup

Comment: @IonLarrañaga As per https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup: "As all functions from Dynamic Memory TR, strdup is only guaranteed to be available if __STDC_ALLOC_LIB__ is defined by the implementation and if the user defines __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__ to the integer constant 1 before including string.h."

Comment: This is a reprroduction example to be honest, in the project the length of the character array is greater.

Comment: @user14063792468 Good to know. Thx!